# How to prove all positive odd numbers in $3x + 1$ will result in even numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was wondering, is there is a generic way to prove that for all positive odd numbers the expression $3x + 1$  will result in even number? I was checking in a brute force way, by writing a program for odd numbers ranging from 1 till Max_long and check if there are numbers which could still result in odd number.
Is there a way to mathematically prove the same ?

Comment: Is there any way you can write all odd numbers in a common way? substitute it into $3x+1$ and see the answer

Comment: $$3(2n-1)+1=2(3n-1)$$

Comment: @user   thanks for pointing it out. I edited the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do note that $3x + 1$ is an *expression*, not an equation. Equations have equality somewhere.

---

As far as proving the statement, notice that the product of two odd numbers is odd, so $3x$ is odd. Then the sum of odd numbers is even, so $3x + 1$ is even. It is a good instructional experience to prove these claims from the definition: Start with $a = 2n + 1$ and $b = 2m + 1$ as your odd numbers, and show that the product $ab$ is of the form $2(...) + 1$ and the sum is of the form $2(...)$.

Answer (score 4):

What you're trying to prove is that if $x$ is odd then $3x+1$ is even. We know that odd numbers are of the form $2k+1, k \in \mathbb{Z}$, and even numbers are of the form $2k, k \in \mathbb{Z}$. So plug in the odd number and see if it is of the form of an even number.
Substitute
$$x=2k+1,k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
into
$$3(2k+1)+1=6k+3+1=6k+4=2(3k+2)$$
Hence the expression results in even numbers if $x$ is odd.

Answer (score 0):

For $3x+1$ to be odd $x$ has to be even starting from $0$ .let us replace $x$ by $r$ so $\sum 3r+1=\frac{3(n)(n+1)}{2}+n=\frac{(n)(3n+5)}{2}$. So summation is always even  independent of $n$ i hope you know the reason.

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't understand what this has to do with the original question. There's no summation in the original.

Comment: I have done the summation of $3x+1$

Comment: Yes, but the original question isn't about summation. It's just the proposition that thrice an odd plus one is odd.

Comment: Rather thrice of even

Comment: Yes, sorry. I got caught up in getting to use "thrice" and was careless :)

Comment: Also you should read the title and body of the question my answer once again. Check what you get on placing 1. So you will know what my result is

Comment: I did, yet I fail to see what this has to do with the summation in your answer (my apologies if I'm missing something obvious).

Comment: See n is tge number of terms so even if its odd or even tge summation of all $3x+1$ will always be even this is how its related